# How come these aliases worked after I closed git bash, but did not work when I tried source ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, aliases

These lines are in my bash_profile:

```
alias md="mkdir"
alias d="date"
alias hy="history"
```

I did source ~/.bash_profile (multiple times lol) but I kept getting "command not found" when trying out my aliases. Then I closed git bash, opened it back up, and voila, the aliases started working. I'm just wondering why they didn't work after I typed out source ~/.bash_profile.

Thanks in advance for any replies (:

Comment: If you say "git bash", I assume you're on windows?

Comment: Yes, afraid so.